# Download files after opening a webpage using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have opened a webpage('http://example.com/protected_page.php') using Python's requests Library.

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': USERNAME,
    'password': PASSWORD
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('http://example.com/login.php', data=payload)
    response = c.get('http://example.com/protected_page.php')
```

Now there are around 15 links on that page to download files.

I wish to download files from only 2 links(say, linkA and linkB).

How can I specify this in my code, so that the 2 files get downloaded when I run my code.

Comment: Where is your code to get the page? Without seeing the page you are trying to scrape your question is unanswerable

Comment: I have added the code in question

Comment: There are lots of sites on the web, each one usually being quite unique

Comment: It is always good to share whatever details you can and the html code of the page so that people can help you. Without knowing the html it is difficult for anyone to provide proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give more information about these links ?

Are these linkA and linkB always the same links ? 
If yes then you can use :

```
r = requests.get(linkA, stream=True)
```

If the url links are not the same all the time , then maybe you can find another way, using the order of the link maybe, for instance if the linkA and linkB is always the first and the second link on the page etc.

Another way is to use any unique class name or id from the page. But it would be better if you could provide us more informations.

Comment: Actually the webpage has 15 different headers (say "H1", "H2", .... , "H15").  So, the header names are same everyday. But, when we click on any header name(say "H1"), the link name(and hence file which is downloaded) changes.

Comment: So, I need some python code in which I can mention the 2 headers which I click daily to download files

Comment: Thats a good start. Inspect the page, and take a look if the headers are linked somehow with links. Then you can use another library like BeatifulSoup4 to get these links and pass them to requests.

Comment: OK Thanks. I also read about Selenium Library.  Can you tell which Selenium Library method can be used to specify header name ?

Comment: Using Selenium is the same process, you have to identify some elements so you can guide your program to click on these buttons or links. You can use class or ids etc. if you can post here some source from your website I could help more. 

At the end of the day , using BeatifulSoup4 or Selenium its the same story. I prefer BS4 personally but Selenium will do the job too.

Answer (score 0):

In fact what you are referring is more precisely called as web scraping , in which one can scrape some specific contents from the given web site:

> Web scraping is a computer software technique of extracting
> information from websites. This technique mostly focuses on the
> transformation of unstructured data (HTML format) on the web into
> structured data (database or spreadsheet).

without knowing the HTML semantics it is not possible to give you a snap of code , for what you are looking for. But here i can advice you some of the way using which you can do web scrape from your site.

**1. Non-programming way:**

> For those of you, who need a non-programming way to extract
> information out of web pages, you can also look at [import.io](http://import.io) . It
> provides a GUI driven interface to perform all basic web scraping
> operations.

**2. Programmers way:**

You may find many libraries to perform one function using python. Hence, it is necessary to find the best to use library. I prefer BeautifulSoup , since it is easy and intuitive to work on. Precisely, you use two Python modules for scraping data:

- > Urllib2: It is a Python module which can be used for fetching URLs. It defines functions and classes to help with URL actions (basic
  > and digest authentication, redirections, cookies, etc). For more
  > detail refer to the documentation page.

- > BeautifulSoup: It is an incredible tool for pulling out information
  > from a webpage. You can use it to extract tables, lists, paragraph and
  > you can also put filters to extract information from web pages. the  latest available  version is BeautifulSoup 4. You can look
  > at the installation instruction in its documentation page.

BeautifulSoup does not fetch the web page for us. That’s why, need to use urllib2 in combination with the BeautifulSoup library.

Python has several other options for HTML scraping in addition to BeatifulSoup. Here are some others:

- *[mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)*
- *[scrapemark](http://arshaw.com/scrapemark/)*
- *[scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)*